# Unit test - Set scope variable for testing directive?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

(I'm using Karma to run Jasmine unit tests.)

My unit test breaks at compile time, even before I have a chance to employ an assertion. The break happens due to an undefined scope variable which the directive's controller logic relies on:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValid' of undefined
```

In the this error, there is an object called "labelCalls" which should have this "setValid" function. (Names are arbitrary, of course.)

Test below:

```
describe("A suite for testing field_label.js directive", function() {

var element, scope;
var formsMock;

beforeEach(
    angular.mock.module('portalApp', function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('TextManip');

        formsMock = {};
        $provide.factory('Forms', function() {
            formsMock.useShorterFieldWidths = function () {
                return true;
            }
            return formsMock;
        });
    })
);

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$compile){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.labelCalls = {};
    element = angular.element('<field-label></field-label>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));

it('should...',function(){

});


});
```

SO, my question is, how do I go about mocking values for these scope variables so that my directive can compile before assertions are run?

Here is the full directive:

```
'use strict';

 portalApp.directive("fieldLabel", function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {formId: '@', fieldDef: '=', isFieldDefEditable: '@', isInvalid: '=', labelCalls: '='},
    template: '<span style="margin-left:0px;">' +
    '<label class="app-form-detail-field tips {{isInvalid ? \' app-form-detail-field-invalid\' : \'\'}}" title="{{tooltip}}">{{labelText}}<sup class="app-form-required-asterisk" ng-show="isRequired">*</sup></label>' +
    '<img class="app-form-detail-img-btn" ng-show="{{editableFieldDefs && !isReadOnly}}" src="framework/images/delete_field.png" ng-click="deleteFieldIcon_Clicked()">' +
    '<img class="app-form-detail-img-btn" ng-show="{{editableFieldDefs && !isReadOnly}}" src="framework/images/edit_field.png" ng-click="editFieldIcon_Clicked()">' +
    '</span>',
    replace: true,
    controller: function ($scope, TextManip, Forms, FieldComponent) {
        var fieldDef = $scope.fieldDef;
        var useShorterFieldWidths = Forms.useShorterFieldWidths($scope.formId);

        $scope.editFieldIcon_Clicked = function () {
            Forms.showEditFieldDialog($scope.formId, fieldDef.field_name);
        };

        $scope.deleteFieldIcon_Clicked = function () {
            Forms.deleteField($scope.formId, fieldDef.field_name);
        };

        $scope.labelCalls.setValid = function (isValid) {
            $scope.isInvalid = !isValid;
        };

        $scope.labelCalls.setNewFieldDef = function (fieldDef) {
            loadScopeBindings(fieldDef);
        };

        var loadScopeBindings = function (def) {
            $scope.fieldDef = def;
            fieldDef = def;

            $scope.editableFieldDefs = ($scope.isFieldDefEditable === 'true');
            $scope.isRequired = (fieldDef.required === 'Y');
            $scope.isReadOnly = (fieldDef.read_only === 'Y');

            var display_name = fieldDef.display_name;
            var abbrev = TextManip.abbreviate(display_name, $scope.editableFieldDefs, $scope.isRequired, useShorterFieldWidths), tooltip = '';

            if (abbrev !== display_name) {
                tooltip = display_name;
                display_name = abbrev;
            }

            $scope.labelText = display_name;
            $scope.tooltip = tooltip;
        };

        loadScopeBindings(fieldDef);
    }
};
});
```

Comment: you are not alone it seems: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19292

Answer (score 0):

can you change your declaration to

```
controller: function ($scope:any, TextManip, Forms, FieldComponent)
```

check out this question: [karma TypeError "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942482/karma-typeerror-cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined?rq=1)

Comment: I don't believe so. My IDE suggests Javascript doesn't support it.

Comment: Ahh.. well who complains about types then?
The message about type error, where does it come from?

Comment: Apologies. I'm using Karma to run Jasmine unit tests.

Comment: Can you check the versions of those?
there is an old issue https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/issues/47
Is it of any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942482/karma-typeerror-cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined?rq=1

Comment: These threads don't seem to have an impact on my issue. I'm using karma-jasmine 2.x already and jasmine 2.9.x.